# hash different strings to same result

Tags: string, hash

I am setting up a voucher code system for a checkout written in C# and I want to be able to distribute unique vouchers that do the same thing, sort of like a product key.

Is there any way of generating unique (fairly short and preferably alpha-numeric) strings that will "hash" in some way to give the same result?

In other words, can I start with a defined voucher code and get multiple results for a reverse hash?

I'm sorry if I'm not explaining this very well - I can give more information if needed.

**EDIT:** I know that I could use a look-up table with pre-defined codes, but I was wondering if there is a way to auto-generate these codes to allow the system to scale easily.

Comment: which programming language? Have you got something like a user id or a e-mail of the person who will get the voucher code?

Comment: The code checking will be in C#, but I can use any method to generate the codes (they will be printed). The codes will be physically printed and handed out so there is no way of tying them to a particular person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a thought...

Start w/ some secret password: "100:mypass:yourpass"

then md5 that: you'll get

```
md5("10:mypass:yourpass")=f6ff5421b31e609c7dcd19c4a462caa0

'key 1'=>  left 16 chars of md5 = 'f6ff5421b31e60'

  run the right 16 chars of the md5 it into another md5:

md5('7dcd19c4a462caa0') = 582fbfb7a035d08094cdef57d88f720e

'key 2' => '582fbfb7a035d080'

[repeat again here, and again... and again, ]
```

...

Not sure on the 'distribution' point on this, e.g. if it will be running on a POS type gift card or voucher card system or what, but if you notice I put 3 components into the 'password', this value *could* contain the total legitimate keys (split on ":", resulting in a break on 100 valid keys ), a system (distributor) password, and a local system password that would be required to 'verify' or 'match' on a 'good' key.  You could just do a quick scan to see if the key exists or not and write an invalidation routine locally.  I know, my math genius friends would probably say there's a better, more secure and effective way but hey... this is what you asked for right?   I'm a simple man and like simple things...   but you could make it more complicated by allowing for ranges too... 
e.g. `pass=> "100:1000:pass1:pass2"` that way you could test the 100->1000th md5's partial keys... 
Cheers!!

Comment: This would appear to be a great solution so I am accepting it. However, what I used in the end was a known string concatenated with a random string and a checksum calculated from the two.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called [Perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

[Here](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~nivio/papers/cikm07.pdf) you can find an article about how to efficiently generate perfect hash for large key sets.

And [here](http://www.dupuis.me/node/9) you can find a c# minimum perfect hash function generator.

Comment: Actually, from your links it looks like I want the opposite. I'm looking for a way of guaranteeing collisions for multiple keys. Also, the full list of keys is not necessarily known before the hash is.

Comment: The last link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a hash generated via the current date/time

```
<!-- language: c# -->
byte[] ByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
byte[] ByteResult = md5.ComputeHash(ByteArray);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(ByteResult.Length * 2);
for (int i = 0; i < ByteResult.Length; i++)
    result.Append(ByteResult[i].ToString("X2"));
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```